# Разобрать mysqli_query

Tags: mysqli

Вот, что выводит print_r($query)

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )
```

Пробовал :

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
print_r($result);
```

Выводит пустую строку.

Мне нужно вытащить значение столбца `company` из данных таблицы.

***Добавлено:***

Запрос:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE `auto_numbers` = 'В132СВ47'");
```

Comment: sql запрос правильный? Проверь в консоли mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых не обязательно, но желательно правильно выбирать имена переменных:
В $query хранить строку запроса к БД. Что-то на подобии

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

В $res(от response или result) заносить результат, который в свою очередь разбивать на строки while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))

А в остальном пустая строка и [num_rows] => 0 - это запрос к БД не возвращает ни единой строчки :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query(...

$result = $query->fetch_row(); // аналог mysql_fetch_row
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче, косяк был в том, что он не принимает русские буквы.